# Checking checkout billing number phone with a specific pattern in WooCommerce

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to make woocommerce phone number start with +370... I have tried this function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'dd_Testval');

function dd_Testval() {
    $billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');

    if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}', '', $billing_phone))) > 0) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Invalid <strong>Phone Number</strong>, please check your input.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

It has no effects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The right way is:

- to use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_checkout_process` action hook instead.
- to use `preg_match()` instead of `preg_replace()`

Now the regex will check that the number phone is starting by **+370**. It will accept after: numbers, white spaces and hyphens characters only, with a minimum total length of 9 characters.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_process');
function custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check the number phone
    if ( isset($_POST['billing_phone']) && ! preg_match("/^(\+370)?[0-9 \-]{5,}/i", $_POST['billing_phone']) )
        wc_add_notice(__('Invalid <strong>Phone Number</strong>, please check your input.'), 'error');
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works